# Keyboard not working anymore

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I am using a MBP 13" 2015. Out of a sudden, the built in keyboard stopped working. At first, the keyboard behaved as if cmd was permanently pressed, later the same for other keys. Some keys sent the characters from an entire column on the keyboard (e.g., a 5 resulted in 5tgb). This changed several times, and right now, no key is working. Even changing brightness or volume fails; the only key still working is the power button.

I

- launched the notebook in safe mode,
- reset the PRAM or whatever you reset by pressing cmd+opt+P+R during startup,
- reinstall mac os (while keeping all files) from the cmd+r menu (which I both did using an external keyboard),
  which all so far brought no success. Do you have any ideas what could have caused the problem and how to solve it? Even the light on the caps lock key is not working.

Nothing special happened since yesterday; I was only surprised that I noticed that the battery was completely drained this morning. The problem appeared when switching on the computer the next time. In particular, the notebook was not exposed to water or anything the like.

Edit: an external keyboard is working.

Comment: Perhaps the battery has swollen (BTDT) and caused the keyboard to be squeezed to failure. Have you tried an external keyboard?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica see edit. The battery is old indeed, and the OS complains about that. I guess the only way to solve this is to have battery (and keyboard?) replaced. Is this link between battery and keyboard common?

Comment: A swollen battery caused trackpad failure on my similar-age MBP. Searching on this site (top of any page) for "Swollen battery keyboard" returns many questions. So I think the answer to "Is it common?" is "Yes."

Comment: If, as seems likely, the keyboard is swollen, you need to be careful. A swollen keyboard can be dangerous - nasty stuff inside which you don't want to released. Get the battery (and keyboard) checked (and probably replaced) before using it again.